# ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code. Metamask while interacting with contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, contract-debugging, gas-price

When I try to interact with my contract (`.vue`, Web3) via Metamask browser extension, I get the warning "`ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.`" when I attempt to buy. The code works, and the site is fine, it's just that when I attempt to transact, I get the error, and the transaction doesn't go through.

Codes: [`Migrations.sol`](https://controlc.com/fe954473),
[`AdSpace.sol`](https://controlc.com/ba6a0d60),
[`App.vue`](https://controlc.com/14feae2f),[`Buy.vue`](https://controlc.com/786532ce),
[`truffle.js`](https://controlc.com/b0e562c3).

`AdSpace.json` is 11385 lines long, please let me know if needed.

I tried debugging with Remix, but it only highlighted that certain parts of the code were deprecated, nothing else. I was also able to successfully deploy the contract to Rinkeby testnet via Remix (for the 2nd time, I first deployed via command line).

[image]

This is what the contract looks like (not my picture, but this how the warning is shown). I have currently only deployed to Rinkeby and used it for all testing also. What could be causing this error?

Thank you.